# Linear regression testing under constraints

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, t-test, f-test

Consider the following regression:
$$Y_i = \alpha + \beta X_i + \epsilon_i.$$
I have to test the following hypothesis:
$$H_0: \alpha = \beta = 0;$$
$$H_1: \alpha \geq 0, \; \beta \geq 0, \quad \alpha \;\text{or}\; \beta \; > 0.$$
In other words, I want to test the null hypothesis that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equal to $0$ against the alternative that both are non-negative and at least one is positive. I understand the logic of the setting, but I do not know how to implement it in practice using F-test or t-test. For example, in Matlab I normally use the function `coefTest` to test linear regression coefficients, but I cannot figure out how to implement this specific framework.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://www.zora.uzh.ch/id/eprint/138641/1/econwp254.pdf

Comment: Here's a [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1912529) which extends Wald and likelihood ratio tests to a setting where we have inequality constraints on the parameters.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean how to implement this in Matlab?

You could always use the Anova function in Matlab to perform F-test.

**sample data

n = 100;
X = rand(n,1);
Y = 2*X + randn(n,1);

**Estimate the regression coefficients

b = regress(Y, [ones(n,1), X]);

**Compute the F-statistic and p-value

SSR = sum((b(1) + b(2)*X - mean(Y)).^2);
SSE = sum((Y - b(1) - b(2)*X).^2);
k = 2;

n = length(Y);
F = (SSR/(k-1))/(SSE/(n-k));
pval = 1 - fcdf(F, k-1, n-k);

**Print

disp(['F-statistic = ' num2str(F)])
disp(['p-value = ' num2str(pval)])

If the p-value is less than the significance level, you can reject the null hypothesis and conclude that at least one of the coefficients is non-zero.

Comment: What if the coefficients are negative?

Comment: Indeed, I do not think this is an answer to the question